# Django filter with bool condition

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

In a view  I want to get a *queryset* of values where only the records that have the value of field **current_num** lesser than **current_tot** are displayed:

I've tried without success:

```
 qs = qs.filter( F('current_tot')!=F('current_num'))
```

If lookup for the less than equal, it works:

```
    qs = qs.filter( current_num__lte=F('current_tot'))
```

If lookup for less than, no result are shown:

```
    qs = qs.filter( current_num__lte=F('current_tot'))
```

Comment: You seem to have copied the same line of code for the one that works and the one that doesn't... should the bottom one be using `__lt`? Are you sure there are results that will match?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use F on the left side of the equality.
To get what you want, use exclude instead of filter :

```
qs = qs.exclude(current_tot = F('current_num'))
```